# how i prevent when the data is inside database than wont insert again

Tags: php, mysql

i was doing a insert statement which if user in the chatroom the active will become 1 but now the db didn't know the data is exits or no so my ajax poll running 2 sec per time. when it load the user will be increase every 2 sec. how i do a checking? when the data is already in database it wont be insert again.

```
<?php

include '../config.php';
include 'login.php';

$id=$_SESSION['id'];
$chatroomid=$_GET['chatroomID'];


$update_status="INSERT INTO user_chat ( `chatroom_id`,`user_id`,`active`)
                VALUES ('$chatroomid','$id','1')
                WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT user_id FROM user_chat WHERE user_id='$id' and chatroom_id = '$chatroomid' and active = '1' 
                )";    
$check_status=mysqli_query($connection,$update_status)or die(mysqli_error($connection));

$online_user="SELECT * from user_chat where active=1";
$all_user=  mysqli_query($connection, $online_user);

$count=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT sum(active) as total from user_chat WHERE active=1  AND chatroom_id='$chatroomid'")or die(mysqli_error($connection));

while ($total_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($count)) {
    echo " Total User : ". $total_user['total']. " " ;
}

?>
```

**update**

now i have an error at `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT user_id FROM user_chat WHERE user' at line 3`

i have relationship with user table

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 1):

check if status is active for pair (user_id, chatroom_id).This will maintain integrity that only once it is there. If there don't insert else insert into table

What you can do: create a UNIQUE INDEX on the field which should be unique (name), then use either:

- normal INSERT (and handle the error if the name already exists using unique constraint index)
- INSERT IGNORE (which will fail silently cause a warning (instead of error) if name already exists)
- insert where not exist

  ```
  INSERT into user_chat( chatroom_id,user_id, active) select ('$chatroomid','$id','1') from dual where not exists  (
      SELECT user_id FROM user_chat WHERE user_id='$id' and chatroom_id = '$chatroomid' and active = 1 
  );
  ```

Eg:--

Try this twice

```
INSERT into user_chat( chatroom_id,user_id, active) select 1,1,1 from dual where not exists  (
        SELECT user_id FROM user_chat WHERE user_id='1' and chatroom_id = 1 and active = 1 
    );
```

On first it will insert , on second time it will ignore.

Comment: i got an error on `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT user_id FROM user_chat WHERE user' at line 3`

Comment: i have a relationship with user table does it need to put in?

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved ur problem. It will help others looking for same problem.